# Get users (sammacountname) in ad group, save them in csv, display all of the groups of these users

Tags: loops, powershell, csv

Im trying to write a script wchich will:
 take members of the specific AD group 
save it to a csv file
print user of the group and all of the groups user is the member of
I want the print results to be in one line

My code looks like this

```
 $group = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the group name'
 Get-ADGroupMember -identity $group -Recursive | % { get-aduser $_} | select SamAccountName | export-csv userzy.csv
$file = import-csv  userzy.csv
ForEach ($user In $file) 
{
 $user
(Get-ADUser $user –Properties MemberOf | Select-Object MemberOf).MemberOf

 }
```

Im stuck when it comes to looping through csv in order to display users and their groups
1. I dont know how to make in one line
2. When im running Get-ADuser in my loop im getting an error:

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value "@{SamAccountName=mczechow}" to type "Microsoft.ActiveDi
rectory.Management.ADUser". Error: "Cannot convert the "@{SamAccountName=mczechow}" value of type "CSV:Selected.Microsoft.Ac
tiveDirectory.Management.ADUser" to type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser"."
At C:\Users\mgiedyk\Desktop\skrypty\groupmembers.ps1:16 char:13
+  Get-ADUser $user -Properties MemberOf
+             ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi, replace `$user` with `$user.SamAccountName`. `$user` is an object here.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that i have to objects learn more objects and reffering to their properties. Will keep it up.

Answer (score -1):

Just replace

> `Get-ADUser $user –Properties MemberOf ...`

to

> `Get-ADUser -Filter{SamAccountName -like $user} –Properties MemberOf ...`